# Laravel Mix and JS - npm run dev - 95% emitting Error: EIO: i/o error, close

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

Whenever I try to run Laravel Mix `npm run dev` with app.js compilation included on my local Laravel 5.5 project, I get following error:

```
95% emittingError: EIO: i/o error, close
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-01-02T17_38_00_013Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-01-02T17_38_00_037Z-debug.log
```

and here is content of log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'development' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v9.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
5 info lifecycle aqualis2@~predevelopment: aqualis2@
6 info lifecycle aqualis2@~development: aqualis2@
7 verbose lifecycle aqualis2@~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle aqualis2@~development: PATH: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/vagrant/aqualis2/node_modules/.bin:/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/vagrant/aqualis2/node_modules/.bin:/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle aqualis2@~development: CWD: /home/vagrant/aqualis2
10 silly lifecycle aqualis2@~development: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle aqualis2@~development: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle aqualis2@~development: Failed to exec development script
13 verbose stack Error: aqualis2@ development: `node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid aqualis2@
15 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/aqualis2
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-51-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.3.0/bin/npm" "run" "development"
18 verbose node v9.3.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error aqualis2@ development: `node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the aqualis2@ development script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is my webpack.min.js file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
// on configure webpack
mix.webpackConfig({
    module:  {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:   require.resolve('pace-progress'),
                loader: 'imports?define=>false',
            },
        ],
    },
    node:    {
        fs: 'empty',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'handlebars': 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js',
        },
    },
});

// on copie les images non ciblées dans les scripts ou feuilles de style
mix.copy('resources/assets/*', 'public');
mix.copy('resources/assets/images/*', 'public/images');

// on compile/minifie les scripts et on isole les vendors
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract([
        'lodash',
        'jquery',
        'admin-lte',
        'lodash',
        'jquery',
        'admin-lte',
        'pace-progress',
        'jquery-slimscroll',
        'fastclick',
        'bootstrap-datepicker',
        'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min',
        'bootstrap-timepicker',
        'bootstrap-colorpicker',
        'icheck',
        'select2',
        'daterangepicker',
        'handlebars',
        'jspdf',
        'html2pdf.js',
        'datatables.net',
        'datatables.net-bs',
        'datatables.net-responsive',
        'datatables.net-responsive-bs',
        'bootbox',
        'moment',
        'moment/locale/fr',
        'highcharts/highstock',
        'highcharts/modules/exporting',
        'highcharts/modules/export-data',
        'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display',
        'pusher-js',
        'laravel-echo',
        'vue'
    ]);

// on compile/minifie la feuille de style pour bootstrap
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/bootstrap.scss', 'public/css/bs.css');

// on compile/minifie la feuille de style pour le thème admin-lte
mix.less('resources/assets/less/adminlte.less', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
    });

// on compile/minifie notre feuille de style perso
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

// on active les sourcemaps
mix.sourceMaps();

// on versionne nos images, scripts et feuilles de style
mix.version();

if (!mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.browserSync(process.env.APP_URL);
}
```

My app.js content:

```
require("./bootstrap");
require("./common");
```

I know this is due to JS because if I comment out the `.extract([...])` and all bootstrap.js content it compiles, but if I have any reference of a library it breaks (for example it breaks if content of bootstrap.js is only `window._ = require('lodash');`

**This is really weird because when I use a fresh new Laravel install, it first works but after any change into webpack.config.js it breaks and rolling it back doesn't help: once it's broken I can't have it working anymore.**

I use Homestead on a Windows 10 machine and node and npm versions are (I tried using nvm to solve the problem but unfortunately it doesn't work):

```
vagrant@homestead:~/laravel_test$ node -v
v9.3.0

vagrant@homestead:~/laravel_test$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Any clue on what's going on?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: what's in `/home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-01-02T17_38_00_013Z-debug.log/` ?

Comment: On your homestead terminal, try running `free -h` to check how much free space have you got left and `free -m` for RAM?

Comment: @RuChernChong Here is the result:
`Mem:           2.0G        260M        966M         43M        774M        1.5G`
`Swap:          1.0G        116K        1.0G`

Comment: I cannot read that sorry. Perhaps you paste this somewhere and link me? Thanks.

Comment: @Victor I added the content in bug description. Thanks

Comment: @RuChernChong I had some trouble to add line in comment, sorry. I fixed it above

Comment: RAM looks okay. Can you run `free -h` to see how much disk space is already used?

Comment: `Mem:           2.0G        246M        684M         33M        1.0G        1.5G` and `Swap:          1.0G          0B        1.0G`

Comment: My bad, it was not `free -h` that I wanted to see. It was `df -h`. However, you have solved your problem now.

Comment: You were also importing jquery two times.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows with vagrant the only solution that works for me is to manually end "NFS server for windows" process from Task Manager and do `vagrant reload`

Comment: This fixed it for me for the same error running gulp.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having same problem, after 2 weeks investigation, I finally found the reason: NFS enabled on vagrant Homestead!!! I simply remove the option and it now works.